# What is the way to write blob content using NestJS?

Tags: node.js, fs, nestjs

After downloading the file from OpenKM, I try to save the file using fs but the file is corrupted, what am missing?

```
const fileContent = await this.getFileFromOpenKM('templates/sample.odt');
const buffer = Buffer.alloc(fileContent.length, fileContent);
fs.writeFile(path.join(directoryPath, 'sample.odt'), fileContent, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

below is the way I have followed to download the file content from OpenKM:

```
async getFileFromOpenKM(uuid: string): Promise<string> {
var URI = "http://localhost:8080/OpenKM/services/rest/document/getContent?docId=" + uuid;

return await this.http.get(URI, { headers: this.headersRequest, responseType: 'blob' })
    .pipe(
        map(response => response.data),
        catchError(err => {
            this.logger.error(`[${OpenKMService.name}]: ${err}`);
            return err;
        }),
    ).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: What format does the file come from OpenKM as? what does `getFileFromOpenKM` return?

Comment: @James it returns doc file in blob format.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like fs changing the content of the file. to move on I have replace it with wget as below:

```
 wget({
    url: process.env.OPENKM_DIRECT_LINK + templatePath,
    dest: filePath,
    headers: this.headersRequest
 },
    function (error, response, body) {
       if (error)
          this.logger.error(error);
    }
 );
```